# Sort multiple lists simultaneously

Tags: python, sorting

I have three lists composed of the same number of elements:

```
a = [0.3, 1.5, 0.2, 2.6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04]
```

I need to sort these three lists simultaneously according to *decreasing values* in list `a`. This means that I have to sort according to `a` but `a` also needs to be sorted.
The output should look like this:

```
a_s = [2.6, 1.5, 0.3, 0.2]
b_s = [4, 2, 1, 3]
c_s = [0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03]
```

This way `a_s` is now simply sorted by decreasing values while `b_s` and `c_s` changed its items positions according to this sorting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Short answer

```
a_s, b_s, c_s = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(a, b, c), reverse=True)))
```

## Long answer

First, you have to zip the three lists, creating a single list of items:

```
>>> a = [0.3, 1.5, 0.2, 2.6]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04]
>>> z = zip(a, b, c)
>>> z
[(0.3, 1, 0.01), (1.5, 2, 0.02), (0.2, 3, 0.03), (2.6, 4, 0.04)]
```

Then, you sort this list. A list of tuples is sorted by their first elements (when first elements are equal, the second one is used, and so on):

```
>>> zs = sorted(z, reverse=True)
>>> zs
[(2.6, 4, 0.04), (1.5, 2, 0.02), (0.3, 1, 0.01), (0.2, 3, 0.03)]
```

Then you "unzip" the list. Unzipping is the same as calling zip with each tuple as argument, which is achieved by using the star syntax:

```
>>> u = zip(*zs)
>>> u
[(2.6, 1.5, 0.3, 0.2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03)]
```

You get a list of tuples, but you want lists. So, you map the list constructor over these items:

```
>>> u
[(2.6, 1.5, 0.3, 0.2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03)]
>>> map(list, u)
[[2.6, 1.5, 0.3, 0.2], [4, 2, 1, 3], [0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03]]
```

You can then unpack the list into variables:

```
>>> a_s, b_s, c_s = map(list, u)
```

## Observations

When sorting, you can explicitly indicate which item will be used for sorting, instead of relying on tuple's default ordering:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(z, key=itemgetter(1))  # Sort by second item
[(0.3, 1, 0.01), (1.5, 2, 0.02), (0.2, 3, 0.03), (2.6, 4, 0.04)]
>>> sorted(z, key=itemgetter(2))  # Sort by third item
[(0.3, 1, 0.01), (1.5, 2, 0.02), (0.2, 3, 0.03), (2.6, 4, 0.04)]
```

Comment: That converts them into tuples, so you might want to do a `map(list,zip(*sorted`...